# Get IP address of a server machine

Tags: networking, nat, synology

There was a robbery at my place and the lads took my NAS. Couple of weeks later I discover my NAS is online again. I access it through a dynamic DNS address that does not give back an IP address with nslookup (Gives back the Synology pool of servers - but cannot http directy to this IP address). It is probably nated behind the returned server. The question is if there were anyway to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question right, the dynamic DNS entry should (as long as your NAS is able to update it) always point to the public IP where your NAS is behind... otherwise it wouldn't be working. If it's at an ISP or larger datacenter and unclear who is really behind this public IP you might want to involve police so they can take the necessary measures.